# converting .wav file to .BS2/BSR file using matlab or any other software

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, bioinformatics

I would like to convert .wav file to .BSR/.BS2 file in matlab.
This is for a post grad project which outputs .wav files from EMG(electromyography) machine.
And this files contain biomedical signals to be processed in matlab after converting them to .BS2/.BSR.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Does the [EMGLAB](http://www.emglab.net/emglab/Software/Software.php) package do what you need?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I dont know much about EMGLAB. I have recieved a .wav file from them and they want to convert it to .BS2 or .BSR file. There is a matlab script to process and analyse this .BS2 or .BSR file.